# Why does Edinburgh Castle's one o'clock gun fire at 1pm instead of, say, noon?

Tags: scotland, time-keeping

Curious to know if there is a specific reason they fire it at 1pm. Noon would make more sense to me!

Comment: How is this not a trivial question?

Comment: If it was fired at Noon they would have to change the name to Noon  Gun ;)

Comment: Citadel Hill in Halifax (Nova Scotia) has a Noon Gun.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[Edinburgh Castle's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edinburgh_Castle) tourist attraction, the [One O'Clock Gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edinburgh_Castle#One_O.27Clock_Gun), originated as an audible version of the [Nelson Monument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_Monument,_Edinburgh) [time ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_ball). The [Nelson time ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_Monument,_Edinburgh#Time_ball) has dropped at 1:00 pm ever since it was installed in 1853. Accordingly, the One O'Clock Gun also fired at 1:00 pm. Anything else would have been potentially confusing.

Time balls were important for maritime towns as a means for ships to set [their clocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_chronometer) to the correct time. This was important for maritime navigational purposes.

In England, time balls typically dropped at 1:00pm. This seems to have begun with [Greenwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Observatory,_Greenwich), which dropped its time ball at 1:00pm from 1833 on, because its astronomers would've been busy with observations at noon.

> One o'clock was chosen as the perfect moment, in order to give the astronomer time to finish his noon observations before the ball was dropped.
>
> **<sub>-  Dibdin, Tim. *Time out guide: Edinburgh, Glasgow,
>   Lothian and Fife*. Penguin, 2000</sub>**

It would have made sense for all the port cities to pick the same time for updating clocks, so as to prevent confusion.

Comment: "Astronomers were busy at noon". Great answer.

Comment: Deleted a very interesting (but OT) discussion about the creation of standard time. That might be good fodder for a question, if asked properly.

Comment: @T.E.D. Perhaps such discussions could be moved into a chat room instead, so passerbys could still read it if they feel so inclined.

Comment: Excellent answer, could not for the life of me figure out why it was at 1pm rather than noon, clears it up nicely!